# Codeblocks with Qt - something terribly wrong

Tags: qt, codeblocks

After creating qt project in codeblocks and running it I'm getting:
[image]

Anyone knows how to resolve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (esp on Windows) a common problem. When installing the Qt SDK, you'll get at least 2 .dll's with the same name but in different versions. It happens, that you link against the intended (dev-)lib but at runtime the version from the Designer/Creator is used.

The easiest way to avoid this, is to deploy the right version of the dll's together with your binaries (.exe and stuff) in a separate folder. This can be achived by modifying your build script. It depends on your build system which is usually qmake/.pro or cmake/CMakeLists.txt.

As for CMake, given an environment variable `MYQTDLLDIR` containing the path to the files to be deployed you can use something like that:

```
configure_file($ENV{MYQTDLLDIR}/QtCore4.dll ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
configure_file($ENV{MYQTDLLDIR}/QtGui4.dll ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
```

documentation stripped from `cmake --help-full`:

> configure_file    Copy a file to another location and modify its
>   contents.
>
> configure_file( 
>                     [COPYONLY] [ESCAPE_QUOTES] [@ONLY])
>
> Copies a file  to file  and substitutes variable
>   values    referenced in the file content.  If  is a relative
>   path it is    evaluated with respect to the current source directory. 
>   The     must be a file, not a directory.  If  is a
>   relative path it is    evaluated with respect to the current binary
>   directory.  If     names an existing directory the input file
>   is placed in that directory    with its original name.
>
> This command replaces any variables in the input file referenced as
>   ${VAR} or @VAR@ with their values as determined by CMake.  If a
>   variable is not defined, it will be replaced with nothing.  If
>   COPYONLY is specified, then no variable expansion will take place.  If
>   ESCAPE_QUOTES is specified then any substituted quotes will be C-style
>   escaped.  The file will be configured with the current values of CMake
>   variables.  If @ONLY is specified, only variables of the form @VAR@
>   will be replaces and ${VAR} will be ignored.  This is useful for
>   configuring scripts that use ${VAR}.  Any occurrences of #cmakedefine 
>   VAR will be replaced with either #define VAR or /* #undef VAR */
>   depending on the setting of VAR in CMake.  Any occurrences of
>   #cmakedefine01 VAR will be replaced with either #define VAR 1 or
>   #define VAR 0 >depending on whether VAR evaluates to TRUE or FALSE in
>   CMake

As for qmake you could use `INSTALLS` (used when `make install` is called) or execute a "plain command" after linking. Using [INSTALLS](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs):

```
mytarget.path = /output/path
mytarget.files += /path/to/QtCore4.dll
mytarget.files += /path/to/QtGui4.dll
INSTALLS += mytarget
```

qmake using command execution:

```
win32 {
    EXTRA_BINFILES += \
        $${MYQTDLLDIR}/QtCore4.dll \
        $${MYQTDLLDIR}/QtGui4.dll
    EXTRA_BINFILES_WIN = $${EXTRA_BINFILES}
    EXTRA_BINFILES_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
        DESTDIR_WIN = $${DESTDIR}
    DESTDIR_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
    for(FILE,EXTRA_BINFILES_WIN){
                QMAKE_POST_LINK +=$$quote(cmd /c copy /y $${FILE} $${DESTDIR_WIN}$$escape_expand(\n\t))
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind and elaborate on this build script mentioned by you. Sounds very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

This looks to me like you're building against one version of Qt and linking against another at runtime. Run the QtSDK Maintenance Tool and remove any versions of Qt Desktop that you don't need. You may then need to repoint Codeblocks at the correct headers.

I'm guessing that if you're running from within Codeblocks, you've had to explicitly specify which dlls to use when you run your newly built app. If so, make sure that those are the correct versions (i.e. replace them with dlls from **QT INSTALL DIR\Desktop\4.7.x\mingw\bin** [though I'm not on my work PC at the moment, so this path may be slightly wrong. Just make sure you're in the correct **4.7.x** folder]).

To be honest though, if you're running from Windows, why not use QtCreator? Aside from slightly lacking in terms of GDB integration, it's pretty good and you'd find problems like this are harder to come across.

Comment: thanks, I use qtcreator for gui design and qt specific code, and business logic in cb. Why? Few reasons, one of them is that I really like cb and wouldn't like to stop using it.